# Putting All csv files in a zip file in Javascript

Tags: node.js, nestjs, jszip

I am trying to make a zip file by using JsZip and FileSaver libraries. I'm using NestJs which is NodeJs framework. But I have a problem. Every Time I try to use the code inside documentation [JSzip Doc](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/), I get a blob error which says "Error: blob is not supported by this platform". I am using node version 16.

I have two method one of them is read the files inside a directory,filter and returns them and another is calls that method inside an array and should make a zip file.

This method reads all files inside *tmp* directory.

```
     async readAllFilesInDirectory() {
    const userHomeDir = os.homedir();
    const tmpDir = path.resolve(userHomeDir, '..', '../tmp');
    console.log(tmpDir);

    try {
      const files = await fs.promises.readdir(tmpDir);
      // console.log(files);
      return files.filter((file) => {
        return !(
          file.startsWith('systemd') ||
          file.startsWith('.') ||
          file.startsWith('snap') ||
          file.startsWith('ssh') ||
          file.startsWith('tracker') ||
          file.startsWith('vscode')
        );
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // console.log(e);
      return [];
    }
  }
```

This function should make zip file with all files inside directory but it doesn't work.

```
  async zipFiles() {
    const allFiles = await this.readAllFilesInDirectory();
    console.log(allFiles);

    var zip = new JSZip();

    zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content) {
      // see FileSaver.js
      FileSaver.saveAs(content, 'test.zip');
    });
  }
```

The given error is :
Error: blob is not supported by this platform

Answer (score 0):

[According to JSZip's documentation](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/write_zip.html) you should be using `zip.generateNodeStream({ type: 'nodebuffer', streamFiles: true })` to generate teh zip instead of using `blob` and you should use the `fs.createWriteStream` API from the `fs` module to write the zip file to the disk. Taking your code it should be something like:

```js
  async zipFiles() {
    const allFiles = await this.readAllFilesInDirectory();
    console.log(allFiles);

    var zip = new JSZip();

    zip.generateNodeStream({ type: 'nodebuffer', streamFiles: true })
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.zip'))
      .on('finish', () => console.log('test.zip written'));
  }
```

Comment: How can I download the test.zip file in my local computer with a written files?

Comment: As in how do you send the zip back over an http response?

Comment: Should I save it as a const declaration?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask here

Comment: My purpose is to download that  zip archive that It has created with zipFiles() function

Comment: Download to the server the zip was created on, or download to the client that is calling the server?

Comment: To download to the server the zip was created on. I would like to download that zip file inside a folder on the server.  It should be automatic, I want to give a path and the server should save files automatically whenever I request a post to the server.

Comment: Then the code above does that already. `zip.generateNodeStream` creates the zip file and `.pipe(fs.createWriteStream())` saves the result of `zip.generateNodeStream` to the file `test.zip`

Comment: Where does the function save `test.zip` file ?

Comment: I believe it should be at `${process.cwd()}/test.zip`